# Tikz node in algorithm2e preventing file from compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithm2e

For some reason, I cannot find where I am going wrong.  I put a tikz node in the algorithm2e environment and now the file cannot compile.  I get the error `Missing } inserted.`  I do not see where I am missing the "}"  Please help me get the file to compile.  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}


\begin{document}
\colorbox{mybluei!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{align*}
 Q_{s} &= \left[ q_{1}, q_{2},...,q_{M-1}\right]
\intertext{Then}
\tikz{\node{$E_{s} &= \subnode(d4){$X$}\subnode(d5){$Q_{s}$} \hspace{1.5cm} \Rightarrow\rho\times(M-1)$};}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw[blue,thick,->] (d4) to [in=90,out=245] + (225:2.7cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {current estimate};
\draw[blue,thick,->] (d5) to [in=90,out=265] +(235:1.8cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {previous estimate};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points: `align` cannot see a `&` that is inside a TikZ `node`. Put `E_s &=` outside the `\tikz`-picture. `\subnode` should be used as `\subnode{d4}{$X$}`, not `\subnode(d4){$X$}` (note braces). And you need to set the baseline of the the `tikzpicture` to something useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{align*}
 Q_{s} &= \left[ q_{1}, q_{2},...,q_{M-1}\right]
\intertext{Then}
E_{s} &= \tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\node(a){\subnode{d4}{$X$}\subnode{d5}{$Q_{s}$} \hspace{1.5cm} $\Rightarrow\rho\times(M-1)$};
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw[blue,thick,->] (d4) to [in=90,out=245] + (225:2.7cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {current estimate};
\draw[blue,thick,->] (d5) to [in=90,out=265] +(235:1.8cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {previous estimate};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]